# What statement is true for this piece of code?

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o

I am preparing myself for my exam, and I am doing some exerices for that - where I came up to a question, I am a little unsure about.

Question:

[image]

I am sure about that the answer can't be C or D because the best running time for the code is O(1) and the worst-case running time is O(n).

I also think B must be the right answer as the if-statement inside the forloop compares if A[i] == 0. Which the worst case is N.

What I am unsure about is, when do you call something "array access" and when it is a comparision? That is why I am unsure about, if the answer is B or A.

Comment: IMO C is the correct answer

Comment: How would C be the right answer? The best-case is constant. What if N = 0?

Comment: C would be correct if it referred to the "worst case". The answer is B. Suppose the loop statement was empty - that's N comparisons (`i < n`) just to run the empty loop. Now consider the statement in the loop, thats another n comparisons. In the worst case there will be 2N comparisons, which is of course O(N).

Comment: if N is anything less than 1 then the loop will not run at all

Comment: And that's why it's constant. Another scenarie:
Assume that S = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} = 5 elements.

When the for-loop runs, it will return 0 at the first run as, s[0] == 0, which is constant.

Comment: It isn't A (there are only N array accesses). Comparing `i` to `n` does not count; you're just comparing one integer against another. The array access happens at `s[i]`.

Comment: B is obviously the answer, but I wonder would the underlying length() needs any array access? Would it be language dependent or it definitely does not contribute any array access?

Comment: yes, if the language uses 0-terminated strings, s.length is already N comparisons and array accesses, and also the worst and the best cases are the same, since it'll always have to (rather pointlessly) loop over all N characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks like you're right.

- Comparisons: Any use of the operators `==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, custom comparison operators or comparison methods.
- Array accesses: Any `arr[i]`, e.g. `arr[i] = x`, `print(arr[i])` or custom accessors, etc.

So just count them up for the best and worst cases.

- What's the worst case? The worst case is when none of the array elements are zero.
- What's the best case? If the first element is zero (we don't count N being zero, because we want to look at totality of the behaviour as N increases).

How many iterations would it have in those cases? How many array accesses and comparisons? Don't forget the comparison ops in the for-loop itself.

Is the algorithm linear or quadratic in the best and worse cases?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is B - in the worst case this code makes a total of 2N comparisons. Suppose the loop was empty. It takes N comparisons (`i < n`) just to run the empty loop. Now consider the `if` statement inside the loop - that is another N comparisons for a total of 2N comparisons in the worst case.

The answer cannot be C, because in the "best case" we discover that the first element of the array is 0 and the loop returns after making only 2 comparisons, making the best case O(1) constant.

The answer is obviously not D; there is nothing quadratic about this loop. Its obviously linear.

The answer cannot be A, because in the worst case we access the array only N times. This occurs at `s[i]`, just prior to the comparison against 0.

Consider the following equivalent code:

```
int n = s.length();
for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    int v = s[i];
    if (v == 0)
        return i;
}
```

Now it should be a little more obvious what counts as a comparison and what counts as an array access. In the worst case we'll access the array N times.